# Proton CEP: How to count distinct instances in temporal context

Tags: fiware

I wish to count the number of distinct visitors to a store each half an hour.

I know I will need:

- the temporal context (half an hour)

What kind of EPA should I create to count distinct visitor ids?

I suppose I will need an internal segmentation by visitorId?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
The EPA should be of type Aggregate.
Yes, you need internal segmentation context by visitorId.
```

See the documentation for a sample which demonstrates how to perform count:
https://github.com/ishkin/Proton/tree/master/documentation/sample/fraud
A pdf doc included.

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to count how many times each user entered the store, then you can use Aggregate EPA with segmentation context on the visitorId as suggested by @urishani.

If you want to count how many distinct visitors entered the store (assuming you can get multiple input events for each visitor), then you need to:

1. Aggregate all the input events related to the same visitor that arrived during a half hour to one event, lets call it distinctVisitor
2. Count how many distinctVisitor events arrived in the previous half hour

To implement (1) I would use an Aggregate type EPA with segmentation context on the visitorId, and an half hour sliding window temporal context. It will have condition that the count over the input events is at least 1, its evaluation policy will be deferred (at the end of the half hour), and it will derive the distinctVisitor event.

To implement (2) I would use an Aggregate type EPA, that will take the distinctVistor as input event, will have sliding window temporal event that will be open every half hour for a short time (lets say 30 second), it will count the number of distinctVisistor events, and its evaluation policy will be deferred. It will not use a segmentation context, since you want to count events of all visitors.